# Error `method_missing': undefined method `has_one_attached' when push heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to move my Ruby Application to Heroku for the first time, first I updated my Ruby version to 2.4.1, I also moved my sqlite3 in development to have :

```
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'sqlite3','~> 1.3.13'
end
```

And now that I can push my app, the app doesnt start and I have the following error "method_missing': undefined method `has_one_attached' for # (NoMethodError)" while running heroku run rails console. Could anybody help me to fix that ?

Comment: what version of rails do you have? does it work locally?

Comment: Thanks for yout answer ! With this configuration no, but when I add gem 'sqlite3' in my gem file, yes. The thing is that gem 'sqlite3' is not supported on heroku as i understood. Do you have any idea how to do ? Edit : to answer your question, I updated my Ruby to the '2.4.1' version.

Comment: I got the answer :  you need to configure your gem file to have squlite3 in development and 'pg' in production as here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297160/detected-sqlite3-gem-which-is-not-supported-on-heroku . Once it's done bundle install and you have to re-create a db on heroku (and maybe modify the access to the db in production).

Comment: Please mark question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because your database is not configured in production on Heroku. The reason why the database is not configured is because Heroku [does not support sqlite3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3).

You need to change your database to use postgresql for production and then push again to your heroku remote.

Instructions on how to do so can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51068610/how-do-i-move-my-existing-rails-app-onto-heroku-sqlite-to-postgres).